# CentOS install php-mbstring error

Tags: php, linux, centos6, mbstring, web-administration

I am trying to install mbstring on CentOS 6.7 with PHP version 7 :

> yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mbstring

, but I get this error:

> php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.45-11.el6.remi.x86_64

CentOS was with default PHP version 5.3 (I think), but before a week I updated it to PHP 7 and now, when I want to install mbstring I see this error.
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a remi package. His packages look like `php-common`, not `php70w-common`. You'll need to edit the `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and enable the PHP 7 repo for his site.

Once you've done that, identify which repo is feeding you `php70w` files and exclude them.

Comment: I just reinstall PHP and after that install mbstring if this help for some1.

Answer (score 0):

php-mbstring for PHP 7 is not in "remi" repository but in "remi-php70" repository, see the [Configuration Wizard](http://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).